# i18n set_locale is not registering

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-i18n

A rails3.2.18 application has the following application_controller method

```
  def set_locale
    if user_signed_in?
      I18n.locale = current_user.idioma.code.downcase
    else
      I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    end
  end
```

a given set of forms which query the application:

```
<%= form_tag @b1, url: results_b1s_path, :validate => true, :method => :get do %>
[...]
<%= submit_tag (t 'submit', locale: I18n.locale.to_s) %>
```

have the query page rendering with the user chosen locale, however the results page are rendered invariably with the default_locale.
Another set of forms using form_for properly render the results according to the defined locale.  The one difference is that they use plain `submit`.

Is it `submit_tag` that is being mis-used, or am I missing something bigger, such as assigning the local as a param to the url under form_for ?  Note:

```
<%= form_tag results_b1s_path, :validate => true, :locale => I18n.locale.to_s, :method => :get do %>
```

has identical behaviour to the first form tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an underlying logic conflict issue between a form, that submits its params and the locale param.

One solution to this is to *partially* steer away from the `param[:locale]` and set a `session[:locale]`, which does make sense from the user perspective.

As can be seen below, user saved locale trumps all.  Then user requested locale will be stored in a session until otherwise defined. The `params[:locale]` does not interfere with the form params.  The logic was previously running with the commented out line.

```
  def set_locale
    if user_signed_in?
      I18n.locale = current_user.idioma.code.downcase
    else
      if !params[:locale].nil?
        session[:locale] = params[:locale]
      end
#      I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
      I18n.locale = session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    end
  end
```